# Express retorno post

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, post, express.js

Boa tarde,

estou com um problema no retorno do POST no express, queria fazer um cadastro de usuários utilizando o seguinte código :

```
router.post('/user', (req,res,next) =>{

  var obj =   {name:req.body.des_name,
              email:req.body.des_email,
              endereco:req.body.des_endereco,
              cep:req.body.num_cep,
              phone:req.body.num_phone,
              password:req.body.des_password}



        user.verifyUserTest(obj.name, function(err, rows) {
             if (rows.length > 0){
               res.send({res : "usuário já cadastrado"})
             }
             else{
              user.setUserByParams(obj,res)
              next()
              }
         })
```

},function(obj,res){

```
res.send("ok")
```

})

estou precisando pegar o retorno do `VerifyUser` para fazer um if caso usuário exista exibir uma mensagem de erro, e caso ele não exista ele chama o next passando Obj como parâmetro para que a outra função `setUserByParams` insira o usuário no banco.

o problema é que o `console.log(user.verifyUser(obj,res))` está retornando undefined e eu precisava que ele retornasse o usuário ou um valor cheio do que mando para o POST

os outros métodos:

Midleware

```
function verifyUser(req,res){

  return con.query(`SELECT * FROM TB_USER WHERE des_name like "${req.name}"`,res)
}
```

DataBase/Consulta:

```
function query(sqlQry,res){
  connection.query(sqlQry,function (err,results,fields) {
    if(err){
      res.json(err)
    }else{
      console.log("Query Executada: "+ JSON.stringify(results))
      res.json(results)

    }
  })
}
```

Detalhe que o envio do post e execução do método está ok porque ele me retorna os objetos contendo o usuário no POSTMAN inclusive eu coloquei um log na query (query executada:) que está me retornando o resultado da query corretamente.

Agradeço a ajuda, Obrigado!.

Código setUsersByParams:

```
function setUserByParams(req,res){

  return con.query(`INSERT INTO db_lifeapp.tb_user (des_name,
                                                    des_email,
                                                    des_endereco,
                                                    num_cep,
                                                    num_phone,
                                                    des_password)
                          VALUES ('${req.name}',
                                  '${req.email}',
                                  '${req.endereco}',
                                  ${req.cep},
                                  ${req.phone},
                                  '${req.password}')`,res)

      }
```

Utiliza a mesma chamada da query do database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de criar lógica assíncrona nesse middleware para esperar a resposta da BD antes de chamar o `next`.  Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
router.post('/user', (req, res, next) => {
  var obj = {
    name: req.body.des_name,
    email: req.body.des_email,
    endereco: req.body.des_endereco,
    cep: req.body.num_cep,
    phone: req.body.num_phone,
    password: req.body.des_password
  }

  user.verifyUser(obj.name, function(err, rows) {
    if (rows.length > 0) next();
    else user.setUserByParams(req, next)
  })
}, function(req, res){
   // esta função corre quando o `next` anterior for chamado 
   // e aqui o utilizador já estava ou está agora registado
   res.send('Ok!');
});

function verifyUser(name, cb) {
  con.query(`SELECT * FROM TB_USER WHERE des_name like "${name}"`, cb)
}

function query(sqlQry, cb) {
  connection.query(sqlQry, cb)
}

function setUserByParams(obj, cb) {
  con.query(`
    INSERT INTO db_lifeapp.tb_user (
       des_name, des_email, des_endereco, num_cep, num_phone, des_password
    ) VALUES (
      '${obj.name}', '${obj.email}', '${obj.endereco}', ${obj.cep}, ${obj.phone}, '${obj.password}')`, cb)
}
```

Eu acho que a lógica do teu código te limita.

Por isso mudei na minha resposta. O que tens (na pergunta) é a resposta desse `SELECT` a ser resolvida dentro dat função `query` com `res.json(results)` e assim não permite o que precisas.

Quem deve tratar esse resultado é a função que chama a query, pois a `função`query` deve ser "cega" e só fazer o que lhe pedem e devolver o resultado.

Comment: no caso então so teria que acrescentar essa parte ?                                          user.verifyUser(obj.name, function(err, rows){
    if (rows.length > 0) next();
    else res.send({err: 'Utilizador não registado'});
  })

Comment: @FelipeSangiorge eu acho que deves mudar o teu código. Dá uma olhada ao comentário que acrescentei na resposta.

Comment: Então a lógica está certa agora, consigo o retorno e validar se o usuário já existe, o problema é que quando ele valida que o usuário não existe, ele segue o next, porém me retorna o erro : `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>[object Object]</pre>
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: @FelipeSangiorge eu usei `{err: 'Utilizador não registado'}` como exemplo. Não sei o que tens no lado do cliente/ajax à espera desse valor. O que queres enviar/mostrar se o utilizador não existir?

Comment: a mensagem está correta porém é um backend quando passa para o next ele teria que cadastrar o usuário, porém retorna esse erro que te mandei e não cadastra o usuário.

Comment: @FelipeSangiorge ah, queres acrescentar um `INSERT` em vez de dar erro? e depois do `INSERT` então chamar o `next()`?

Comment: não no caso a propria função `setUserByParams` já tem um insert, inclusive já foi até testado, essa função chama um insert passando um objeto como parametro e os valores desse objeto são inseridos na query, o problema é que acho que nem está chamando o next, tentei dar um console antes de chamar `setUserByParams` e não roda o console.

Comment: @FelipeSangiorge ah, ok. Na verdade isso faz-me ver um erro na minha resposta que vem da tua lógica. Mais uma vez, não faças `res.send()` dentro de funções especializadas. O papel delas é fazer uma tarefa específica e não dar retorno   ao cliente. Coloca o código de `setUserByParams` que atualizo a resposta.

Comment: Opa coloquei lá, eu criei um metodo queryTest e verifyUserTest colocando os parametros que você passou na resposta, tentei chamando tanto query quanto query teste e retornou aquele erro.

Comment: @FelipeSangiorge dá uma olhada agora

Comment: Agora deu certo @Sergio só dei uma editada no routes, porque o if rows >0 deve rodar se o usuário existir então retorna a mensagem que já existe, caso contrario executa a outra função, mas isso ai Muito obrigado mesmo !, vou postar como concluído valeu!!! ajudou muito!

Comment: @FelipeSangiorge ótimo!