# Erro: "Can't set headers after they are sent" no Node.js / Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Tenho o seguinte método :

```
//USER_POST
  router.post('/user', (req,res,next) =>{

      var obj =   {name:req.body.des_name,
                  email:req.body.des_email,
                  endereco:req.body.des_endereco,
                  cep:req.body.num_cep,
                  phone:req.body.num_phone,
                  password:req.body.des_password}



            user.verifyUser(obj.name, function(err, rows) {
                 if (rows.length > 0){
                   res.send({res : "usuário já cadastrado"})
                 }
                 else{
                  user.setUserByParams(obj,res)
                    res.send({res: "usuário cadastrado com sucesso!"})
                  }
             })
  })
```

Quando caio na validação de que o usuário já existe recebo o retorno de que ele já existe, a aplicação continua funcionando normalmente, porém quando caio na validação de novo usuário, onde eu sou informado de que o usuário foi cadastrado ( o mesmo é registrado na base tudo certo) porém a aplicação da erro e recebo a seguinte mensagem : (utilizo o postman para testar)

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:357:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at Query._callback (C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\config\database.js:23:11)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:88:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.OkPacket (C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:72:10)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Esse erro acontece quando fazes `res.send` duas vezes para o mesmo pedido. Dá uma olhada em `user.setUserByParams` se o `res` não está a ser usado lá.

Comment: Opa era isso mesmo, sem perceber minha database retornava um res rsrs coloca a resposta pra eu marcar como concluido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relembrando [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/245437/129) vi que o código de é:

```js
function setUserByParams(req, res) {
  return con.query(`
    INSERT INTO db_lifeapp.tb_user (
      des_name, des_email, des_endereco, num_cep, num_phone, des_password
    ) VALUES (
      '${req.name}', '${req.email}', '${req.endereco}', ${req.cep}, ${req.phone}, '${req.password}'
    )
  `, res);
}

function query(sqlQry, res) {
  connection.query(sqlQry, function(err, results, fields) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err)
    } else {
      console.log("Query Executada: " + JSON.stringify(results))
      res.json(results)
    }
  })
}
```

O que acontece é que estás a enviar `res.send` dentro de `query` e em `user.setUserByParams(obj,res)`. Deves remover esses `res.send` de funções especializadas como uma query à BD [como sugeri na outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/245437/129).

Assim devias fazer:

```js
function query(sqlQry, cb) {
  connection.query(sqlQry, cb);
}
//USER_POST
router.post('/user', (req, res, next) => {
  var obj = {
    name: req.body.des_name,
    email: req.body.des_email,
    endereco: req.body.des_endereco,
    cep: req.body.num_cep,
    phone: req.body.num_phone,
    password: req.body.des_password
  }
  user.verifyUser(obj.name, function(err, rows) {
    if (rows.length > 0) {
      res.send({
        res: "usuário já cadastrado"
      })
    } else {
      user.setUserByParams(obj, function(err) {
        if (err) console.log(err); // eventualmente avisar com res.send também
        else res.send({
          res: "usuário cadastrado com sucesso!"
        })
      });
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Eu fiz essa edição e acabei removendo, vou deixar o res.send do banco so para requisições get, que precisam retornar os valores mesmo, Muito Obrigado!